# How to add a column specific with values depending on other cell's value using javascript or php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

Let's say for example column dropdown represents a type of membership and depending on the value of dropdown, I would like to be able to display a column next to it that indicates the maximum number of companions I could bring. Is there a way to do it via javascript or PHP or maybe SQL itself?

```
<?php
        foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $rows){
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $rows['name']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['email']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['number']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['org']?></td>     
            <td><?php echo $rows['dropdown']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['date']?></td>
        </tr>
     <?php
      }
     ?>
```

Comment: Of course it is possible using JavaScript. What have you tried, what has your research turned up?

Comment: Thanks Willie for the revisions. Also, this is kinda my logic where it still needs of fixing.

Logic on the front end

Find the total number of rows
loop through each of the rows

x = 1st 

if type of member  is this, then 
 td's data should be something

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
<?php
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $rows){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td id="<?=$rows['id']?>"><?php echo $rows['name']?></td>
    </tr>
 <?php
  }
 ?>
```

By clicking on the ajax button you will take the ID attribute of the column, send a request with the received id and add the value to the column created next to it.

If I understand you correctly.

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment. I was thinking maybe just use javascript on this. Do you know any way?

Comment: @RachetandClank Do you want me to write the JS code that I described above?

Comment: yeah. Thanks I would love that